# How to convert for loop into while loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How to convert the for loop below into a while loop?

```
for (j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++, i++)
    sen[i] = s1[j];
```

I tried to convert but got any empty result, not sure what is wrong with this:

```
while (j= 0, s1[j] != '\0') {
    j++, i++;
    sen[i] = s1[j];
}
```

The original code is below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdafx.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Bad";
    char s1[] = "weather!";
    char sen[10];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<20; ++i){
        if (s[i] != '\0')
            sen[i] = s[i];
        else {
            sen[i++] = ' ';
            for (j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++, i++)
                sen[i] = s1[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    sen[i] = '\0';
    puts(sen);
}
```

Comment: Take time to read how to use the while loop. This might help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop

Comment: Instead of writing `while`-loops, perhaps you should read up on [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat).

Answer (score 4):

My general take on the C language `for` statement is that it is a compact version of the `while` statement. There are some little differences when using `continue`, but apart from that, this is the general bijective conversion:

```
for (expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3) {
   statements;
}
```

becomes

```
expr1;
while (expr2) {
   statements;
   expr3;
}
```

So if you apply this to your case:

```
for (j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++, i++)
sen[i] = s1[j];
```

you get that

```
expr1      <==>   j = 0
expr2      <==>   s1[j] != '\0'
expr3      <==>   j++, i++
statements <==>   sen[i] = s1[j];
```

so the conversion is the same as the one suggested by @user2233706.

```
j = 0;
while (s1[j] != '\0') {
   sen[i] = s1[j];
   j++, i++;
}
```

Anyway, the original code is terrible for a long set of errors. Her we go:

- `#include <stdafx.h>` --> don't use this for C code under Visual Studio. Prefer empty projects to make them portable. (my opinion)
- `int main()` --> should be `int main(void)` to be standard.
- `char sen[10];` --> this array can contain 9 characters plus a terminator. `"Bad weather!"` requires 12 plus a terminator.
- `for (i = 0; i<20; ++i){` --> why 20?
- `s[i] != '\0'` --> Do yourself a favor: write it as `s[i] != 0`, to stress that it's not a magic value. Is just a 0. (my opinion)
- `sen[i] = s[i];` --> you didn't check if `i` is lower than the size of `sen`
- the `for` within the `else` is totally independent of the external one, so why nesting them?

Answer (score 1):

```
j = 0;

while(s1[j] != '\0')
{
  sen[i] = s1[j];
  i++;
  j++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SamaelSaverem if the answer is good then you should up vote it. If it solved your question then you should accept it.

Comment: What `break` always executes here?

Comment: Sorry, thought the break was inside the for loop.